# SQL query parsing Issue with joining a table with a view for apex tabular form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using the following SQL query as a basis for an Apex tabular form:

```
SELECT G."INDICATOR_NAME", V.INDICATOR_TYPE, V.INDICATOR_PERIOD, V.INDICATOR_VALUE, V.METRIC_USER, V."METRIC_USER_GROUPID"
FROM STG_VALUES  V, "#OWNER#"."GETMETRICGROUPID_V" G WHERE V.INDICATOR_NAME = G."INDICATOR_NAME" AND V.METRIC_USER_GROUPID = G."METRIC_USER_GROUP_ID"
and  V.INDICATOR_PERIOD BETWEEN  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-36), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Here I'm joining a `table (STG_VALUES)` with a `view (GETMETRICGROUUPID_V)`

Here's the script for the GETMETRICGROUPID_V:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW STG.GETMETRICGROUPID_V
(
   INDICATOR_NAME,
   METRIC_USER_GROUP_ID
)
AS
   SELECT INDICATOR_NAME, METRIC_USER_GROUP_ID
     FROM STG_MST_USER_ASSIGNED_METRICS
    WHERE    METRIC_USER = NVL (v ('APP_USER'), USER)
          OR METRIC_USER = LOWER (NVL (v ('APP_USER'), USER));
```

Here's my issue:

When I ran the above SQL Query in the Apex SQL Commands area, I got the
correct results.  But when I used the same SQL Query inside the Apex tabular
form, I received the following error message:
failed to parse SQL query:
ORA-01403: no data found

It looks like Apex has issues joining a table with a view when used as a basis for the tabular form.  Any thoughts on this ?  I've searched the Internet for
answers/solutions and could not find any.

olecramon74

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01403:no data found` comes when the Select query returns no result in a PL/SQL code or function. Check the output of the v ('APP_USER') function in the query, it should be returning no result when you are running the query from APEX

Comment: Thanks Vishad for your suggestion.  I just used a subquery as part of the base query for the form and drop the use of the view.  Using the view tries to extract the current user from the database and not from the APEX login form.